# Media Wiki - Applying a template prograitically

Tags: templates, mediawiki, wiki

i've been searching for an answer to this and I can't find anything, it might be that its just not possible.

However, if i create a template and someone wants to use it, they typicaly have to create a page, pop in teh syntax, save it, and then edit it once the template has been applied. This is sometimes a challenge for my basic user to follow and we are trying to drive adoption of the wiki internally.

So I ask, it is possible to generate a link that will create a named page, and apply the temaplte at creation time so that the very first edit, people are simply editing the formatted page?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [preload](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Creating_pages_with_preloaded_text) parameter. If you need flexibility with the page name, the [InputBox](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:InputBox) extension can help further.